# Align first text to right of image and then second text below image

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I am working on an "about" page at http://invisionbilling.com/about/. I am trying to place the name directly below the image and the description to the right of the image. I am not sure how much information will be on this page, but I want to make sure that the description will wrap around the image and name if it goes past the picture. Does someone know how to do this? Below is my HTML and CSS. Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="about_image">
<span class="about_text">
<img class="about_image1" src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/07/Profile-Pic.jpg" />
***All the wording I won't place in here.
</span>
<div class="picture_name">
<span class="picture_text">Jane Doe</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.about_image1 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.about_image {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.picture_text {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.picture_name {
    clear: left;
    align-items: below;
}
```

Comment: try to remove display flex

Answer (score 0):

```css
.about_image1 {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.about_image {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.picture_text {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.picture_name {
   position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_image">
<span class="about_text">
<img class="about_image1" src="http://invisionbilling.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/07/Profile-Pic.jpg" />
***All the wording I won't place in here.
</span>
<div class="picture_name">
<span class="picture_text">Jane Doe</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: just change this it will go under the image .picture_name {
   position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

Comment: I made that change but the name is still not going under the image.